# How disable javascript effect on separated input field?

Tags: javascript, field

This is the Javascript that turns on Georgian keyboard in every input and textarea field

But I have one input field with ID user_login which type is text and of course, this javascript takes effect on this field too
I simply want to disable the effect of this javascript only for this field which ID is user_login

Please help me
thank you in advance

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.geokbd.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery_min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.geokbd.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="gk-switcher">
<input id="kbd-switcher" type="checkbox">
</div>

<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description">
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password">
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email">
</form>

    <input placeholder="Email" type="email">
    <input placeholder="About me" maxlength="11" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Username:" type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="wide">

    <script>
$('#kbd-switcher').geokbd();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and code

```js
(function($, undefined) {

$.fn.geokbd = function(options) {
    var 
    isOn, 
    inputs = $([]),
    switchers = $([]),
    defaults = {
        on: true,
        hotkey: '`'
    },
    settings = (typeof options === 'object' ? $.extend({}, defaults, options) : defaults);

    // first come up with affected set of input elements
    this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is(':text, textarea')) {
            inputs = inputs.add($this);
        } else if ($this.is('form')) {
            inputs = inputs.add($this.find(':text, textarea'));
        } else if ($this.is(':checkbox')) {
            if (!inputs.length) {
                inputs = $(':text, textarea');
            }
            switchers = switchers.add($this); // store the checkboxes for further manipulation
        }

        if (typeof settings.exclude === 'string') {
            inputs = inputs.not(settings.exclude);
        }
    });

    // mutate switchers
    switchers
        .click(function() { toggleLang() })
        .wrap('<div class="gk-switcher"></div>')
        .parent()
            .append('<div class="gk-ka" /><div class="gk-us" />');

    // turn on/off all switchers
    toggleLang(isOn = settings.on);

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(e.which), kach;

        if (settings.hotkey === ch) {
            toggleLang();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (!isOn || !inputs.filter(e.target).length) {
            return;
        }

        kach = translateToKa.call(ch);

        if (ch != kach) {
            if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer")!=-1) {
                window.event.keyCode = kach.charCodeAt(0);
            } else {
                pasteTo.call(kach, e.target);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });

    function toggleLang() {
        isOn = arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : !isOn;
        switchers
            .each(function() {
                this.checked = isOn;
            })
            .closest('.gk-switcher')[isOn ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('gk-on');
    }

    // the following functions come directly from Ioseb Dzmanashvili's GeoKBD (https://github.com/ioseb/geokbd)

    function translateToKa() {
        /**
        * Original idea by Irakli Nadareishvili
        * http://www.sapikhvno.org/viewtopic.php?t=47&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=10
        */
        var index, chr, text = [], symbols = "abgdevzTiklmnopJrstufqRySCcZwWxjh";

        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            chr = this.substr(i, 1);
            if ((index = symbols.indexOf(chr)) >= 0) {
                text.push(String.fromCharCode(index + 4304));
            } else {
                text.push(chr);
            }
        }
        return text.join('');
    }

    function pasteTo(field) {
        field.focus();
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            if (range) {
                range.text = this;
            }
        } else if (field.selectionStart != undefined) {
            var scroll = field.scrollTop, start = field.selectionStart, end = field.selectionEnd;
            var value = field.value.substr(0, start) + this + field.value.substr(end, field.value.length);
            field.value = value;
            field.scrollTop = scroll;
            field.setSelectionRange(start + this.length, start + this.length); 
        } else {
            field.value += this;
            field.setSelectionRange(field.value.length, field.value.length);    
        }
    };
}

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Your code runs when you call your plugin on the `kbd-switcher` checkbox. It then tries to loop over the checkbox (`$this.each()`), which doesn't make much sense and also tries to find elements within the checkbox. Fundamentally, you are looking for the elements to add the effect to in the wrong place.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not an educated person in javascript and I don't understand everything, so it is a javascript problem and no chance to fix it? I mean to disable an effect on input with my ID I already mentioned?

Comment: Of course there is a way to fix it, but what I'm saying to you is that most of an entire section of your code is incorrect and we generally don't just rewrite code. We expect that you'll do your research and have some knowledge of the code you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call your plugin on the `form` element, instead of the checkbox and then search the document for all desired element types except the one with the `id` of `user_login`, your `inputs` JQuery wrapper will only contain the elements you want.

```js
(function($, undefined) {

$.fn.geokbd = function(options) {
    var 
    isOn, 
    inputs = $([]),
    switchers = $([]),
    defaults = {
        on: true,
        hotkey: '`'
    },
    settings = (typeof options === 'object' ? $.extend({}, defaults, options) : defaults);

    // first come up with affected set of input elements
    // Using the standard DOM API, search the document for all `input` and 
    // 'textarea' elements, except for the one with an id of: "user_login"
    document.querySelectorAll("input:not(#user_login), textarea").forEach(function(item) {
        var $this = $(item);
        // You had the selector for an input incorrect
        if ($this.is('input[type="text"], textarea')) {
            inputs = inputs.add($this);
        } else if ($this.is('form')) {
            inputs = inputs.add($this.find('input[type="text"], textarea'));
        } else if ($this.is(':checkbox')) {
            if (!inputs.length) {
                inputs = $('input[type="text"], textarea');
            }
            switchers = switchers.add($this); // store the checkboxes for further manipulation
        }

        if (typeof settings.exclude === 'string') {
            inputs = inputs.not(settings.exclude);
        }
    });

    // mutate switchers
    switchers
        .click(function() { toggleLang() })
        .wrap('<div class="gk-switcher"></div>')
        .parent()
            .append('<div class="gk-ka" /><div class="gk-us" />');

    // turn on/off all switchers
    toggleLang(isOn = settings.on);

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(e.which), kach;

        if (settings.hotkey === ch) {
            toggleLang();
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        if (!isOn || !inputs.filter(e.target).length) {
            return;
        }

        kach = translateToKa.call(ch);

        if (ch != kach) {
            if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer")!=-1) {
                window.event.keyCode = kach.charCodeAt(0);
            } else {
                pasteTo.call(kach, e.target);
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });

    function toggleLang() {
        isOn = arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : !isOn;
        switchers
            .each(function() {
                this.checked = isOn;
            })
            .closest('.gk-switcher')[isOn ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('gk-on');
    }

    // the following functions come directly from Ioseb Dzmanashvili's GeoKBD (https://github.com/ioseb/geokbd)

    function translateToKa() {
        /**
        * Original idea by Irakli Nadareishvili
        * http://www.sapikhvno.org/viewtopic.php?t=47&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=10
        */
        var index, chr, text = [], symbols = "abgdevzTiklmnopJrstufqRySCcZwWxjh";

        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            chr = this.substr(i, 1);
            if ((index = symbols.indexOf(chr)) >= 0) {
                text.push(String.fromCharCode(index + 4304));
            } else {
                text.push(chr);
            }
        }
        return text.join('');
    }

    function pasteTo(field) {
        field.focus();
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.selection.createRange();
            if (range) {
                range.text = this;
            }
        } else if (field.selectionStart != undefined) {
            var scroll = field.scrollTop, start = field.selectionStart, end = field.selectionEnd;
            var value = field.value.substr(0, start) + this + field.value.substr(end, field.value.length);
            field.value = value;
            field.scrollTop = scroll;
            field.setSelectionRange(start + this.length, start + this.length); 
        } else {
            field.value += this;
            field.setSelectionRange(field.value.length, field.value.length);    
        }
    };
}

$('form').geokbd();

}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.geokbd.css">

    </head>
    <body>

<div class="gk-switcher">
<input id="kbd-switcher" type="checkbox">
</div>

<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description">
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password">
    <input placeholder="Email" type="email">
</form>

    <input placeholder="Email" type="email">
    <input placeholder="About me" maxlength="11" type="text">
    <input placeholder="Username:" type="text" name="user_login" id="user_login" class="wide">

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: no, it's not working, anyway, javascript has effect on input with id user_login

Comment: @SPoX Would you please edit your question and include the relevant HTML so we can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Edited check html of the input field

Comment: @SPoX No, please add ***all*** the relevant HTML, not just the one field you're asking about. We need to be able to reproduce what's happening. If right now all the fields are being affected, we need to have the code for all those fields as well.

Comment: @SPoX Take a look at my updated answer and see if it helps.